# To find edge directional distribution features

Tags: matlab

How can I solve my error when I apply this code ?

[image]

notice: B is image.

The problem which appear is:

[image]

Comment: Try to post your code in the question, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

As your loop goes from `0` to the maximum number of rows and columns, when your index `i` is equal to the index of the last row, you are trying to reach the row `i+1` which doesn't exist (same applies for column `j+1`). Your loops should go up to `r-1` and `c-1` only.

`i` should also start at `2` as you are trying to access the index `i-1`.

Comment: but when i put loops go up to r-1 and c-1 , will lose one pixle

Comment: Then tell me what is `B(i+1, j)` when `i` is equal to the number of rows (the last row of the image)...

Comment: i try to apply method that will apply "and" function beteen each pixle and its neighborhood

Comment: You need special processing for the pixels on the border of your image. The bottom row pixels have no neighboring pixel below them. This is the reason why Matlab raises an error.